# How to do selective combination in Python List?

Tags: python, loops, recursion, combinations

I'm not really sure how to frame my question, but here's a try. I have a list of strings and tuples of strings. I want all combinations such that I pick only one value from each tuple.

It's much easier to demonstrate with an example.

Input:

`x = ['a', ('b', 'c'), ('d', 'e'), 'f']`

Output:

```
y = [
    ['a', 'b', 'd', 'f'],
    ['a', 'c', 'd', 'f'],
    ['a', 'b', 'e', 'f'],
    ['a', 'c', 'e', 'f']
]
```

Example 2:

Input:

`x = ['a', ('b', 'c'), ('d', 'e'), 'f', ('g', 'h')]`

Output:

```
y = [
    ['a', 'b', 'd', 'f', 'g'],
    ['a', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g'],
    ['a', 'b', 'e', 'f', 'g'],
    ['a', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'g'],
    ['a', 'b', 'd', 'f', 'h'],
    ['a', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'h'],
    ['a', 'b', 'e', 'f', 'h'],
    ['a', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'h']
]
```

Comment: What have you tried ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x = ['a', ('b', 'c'), ('d', 'e'), 'f', ('g', 'h')]
```

First normalize your input

```
x = [tuple(xx) for xx in x if not isinstance(x, tuple)]
```

Then:

```
import iterools
list(itertools.product(*x))
```

In the output your have a list of tuples, it should be very easy to get list of list as you want.

Actually the normalization step is not necessary.

Comment: Thank you very much.. it's so succinct.